# $f \in \mathcal{C}(X, X)$ on metric space with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) < \infty$ has a fixpoint

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $f : X \to X$ continuous such that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) < \infty $$
>   for all $x, y \in X$, where $f^n$ means $f \circ \ldots \circ f$ $n$-times.
>   Then $f$ has a fixpoint.

Since the sum convergence, for all $x, y \in X$ it's true that $d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) \longrightarrow 0$. How can I go from here? The fact that $f$ is continuous is essential, isn't it?

Comment: Adds on Robert Israel's comment : Since $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\ d(f^n(x),f^{n+1}(x)) <\infty$, then
$x_n=f^n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence so that $\{x_n\}$ has a limit
point $x_\infty$, since $X$ is a complete space. Hence
$d(x_\infty,x_n)\rightarrow 0$ so that
$d(f(x_\infty),f(x_n))\rightarrow 0$, since $f$ is continuous. Here
$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ goes to $f(x_\infty)$. By uniqueness of limit
point, $x_\infty$ is a fixed point.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show for any $x$, $f^n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. What does it mean for $a$ to be a fixed-point of the mapping $f$?
2. To prove two things are equal, it's enough to prove their distance is zero.
3. Yes, continuity is essential.
4. There's another hypothesis that you have not used yet.